# PHP Session not working inside a function

Tags: php, session, pdo

I have a function which is men't to insert specific data into a database after someone has purchased an item via paypal and I need it to insert a username into the database, the username is stored in a session and for some strange reason that session wont work even when writing `session_start();` even in the function where that function is being called in.
Heres my code:

```
    function insert_data($request){
    session_start();
    require_once('../pdo_connect.php');


$post=$request;
$item_name=$this->issetCheck($post,'item_name');
$amount=$this->issetCheck($post,'mc_gross');
$txn_id=$this->issetCheck($post,'txn_id');
$payment_status=$this->issetCheck($post,'payment_status');
$payer_id=$this->issetCheck($post,'payer_id');
$payer_user=$_SESSION['username'];

$send_values = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO transactions (item_name,amount,txn_id,payment_status,payer_user) VALUES (:scriptname,:amount,:txnid,:paymentstatus)");

    $send_values->bindParam(':scriptname',$item_name);
    $send_values->bindParam(':amount',$amount);
    $send_values->bindParam(':paymentstatus',$payment_status);
    $send_values->bindParam(':txnid',$txn_id);
    $send_values->bindParam(':payeruser',$payer_user);


$send_values->execute();    

    }
```

Im not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Thank you in advanced :)

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION);`

Comment: My bet would be that session_start(); is not declared before you create $_SESSION['username']. Ideally keep it top most file and start only once.

Comment: ["username"]=> string(9) "wafflezzz"

Comment: So I should keep it up here <?php
session_start();


class Script_Buy{

Comment: then later on the functions are called

Comment: doesnt work right at the top

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: the problem is I cant exactly view the page because paypal sends the info over to that file

Comment: is this an IPN script? then the is no user so no session

Comment: when you login a session is created showing your name. When someone pays the IPN Script validates it then sends information to the database.

Comment: but is this hit by paypal or a human?

Comment: I think I have an idea on how to pass the variables through, gonna do it directly through the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
$form .= '<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="' . $data['username'] . '" />';
```

What it does is sends those values to paypal but because its called custom paypal does nothing with them and sends them to the IPN Listener.

Comment: you can parse pay-pal i certain number of 'free' fields (3 i think) that it will parse back untouched, you should use that